# How to make our own HOME-SCREEN & take only one button/icon on Home Screen in Android?

Tags: android

I just want to make my own HOME-SCREEN in android. I also want to call that HOME-SCREEN from my `Activity`. How to achieve it?
I just want to put one button on that HOME-SCREEN.

So, please tell me the exact solution.  I have read this content from 
[this dev site](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html).
but I am getting actual process to make our Home-Screen in dev site. Home code doesn't have `Activity` class and all so I am not understanding.
Can any one please help me to understand this concept?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. In there is where you tell android that this application is meant to be a home app:

```
    <activity android:name="Home"
            android:theme="@style/Theme"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The class extending `Activity` is `Home` itself:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/src/com/example/android/home/Home.html

```
public class Home extends Activity {
// many lines chopped
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
// many lines chopped
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        // Close the menu
        if (Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            getWindow().closeAllPanels();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
// many lines chopped
    }
// many lines chopped etc
}
```

Comment: @aleadam actually i have read that code provided at developer site.but what i am not getting that,not single Activity class they have written in the code.mu use case as follows:1)i have one activity in which there is full-screen image.now i want to show that full-screen image as my Home Screen.for that i must create my own Home screen??So how can i achieve it.???please help me for the same...

Comment: I hope the extended answer will shed some light into it. In short, yes, you will use your class that extends `Activity` for your `android.intent.category.HOME` as detailed in the xml file.

Comment: @aleadam Thanks alot. can we override Home Button on our own Home-screen??

Comment: yes, like in any other app, but that's a completely different question (try to keep one topic per question).

Comment: Okey....thanks a lot....i will first create my own Home-Screen and then will contact you for overriding Home Button....

Comment: @Smith hi i am new in android i also want to know how to make customize home screen for android. so please u can help me. please its great for me and if u help me. i want to do same thing so please tell me what steps i have to perform to achieve this things